# How to Upgrade Master Slave MySQL on AWS RDS?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds

I already have Master Slave configuration on AWS RDS. We want to upgrade 5.5 to 5.6.23. ..What should be correct sequence to Upgrade ?

1. Upgrade Master ( Using Modify Instance ) --> Upgrade Slave
2. Upgrade Master  ( Using Modify Instance ) --> Create a new Read Replica ?

Answer (score 1):

Look for Amazon instructions.  With RDS, the instructions are roughly:

1. Upgrade the Slave first.  Replication works when the Master is 'older'.
2. Failover, but do not turn on the Slave.
3. Upgrade the Slave (was Master)
4. Turn on replication (START SLAVE)
5. Wait for replication to catch up before using the Slave.

Comment: At suitable points, turn on/off `readonly`.

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially face few issues like if you have scheduler events configured etc... I will recommend safest and easiest way is to upgrade master and recreate the slave.